# How to select text before and after <br> in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xpath

How can I select texts that are not surrounded by HTML tags, but simply preceding and following `<br>` tags ?

I did it with xpath:

```
.xpath('//br/following-sibling::text()|//br/preceding-sibling::text()')
```

Comment: you mean 'extract the text without html line breaks'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var text = "";

$("br").parent().contents().each(function(i) {
    if(this.nodeName == "#text")
    {
        text += this.textContent;
    }
});

alert(text);
```

--->

```
<span>bla bla bl<br/>a bla...</span> --> bla bla bla bla...
```